# The density one properties of $\mathcal H^{N-1}$-rectifiable set

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $S\subset \mathbb R^N$ be a $\mathcal H^{N-1}$-rectifiable set. Then we know that there exist countably many Lipschitz $N-1$-graphs $\Gamma_i\subset \mathbb R^N$ such that 
$$
\mathcal H^{N-1}\left(S\setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \Gamma_i\right)=0
$$
Without lose of generality, we assume that 
$$
\mathcal H^{N-1}(\Gamma_i\cap \Gamma_j)=0\text{ if }i\neq j
$$
Hence, for $\mathcal H^{N-1}$ a.e. $x\in S$, there exists only one $\Gamma_i$ such that $x\in\Gamma_i$, and let us name this $\Gamma_i$ by $\Gamma_x$.

My question: would it possible to hold that 
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\mathcal H^{N-1}(\Gamma_x\cap B(x,r))}{r^{N-1}}=1
$$
for $\mathcal H^{N-1}$ a.e. $x\in S$?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding you again, but: once you fix $x \in S$, $\Gamma_x$ is just a Lipschitz graph which has density $1$ at almost all its points, which is the statement you want to hold. If your assumptions above about mutual intersections are correct, I don't see why it shouldn't, but I could have missed something, if so, please let me know.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi I think you understand me perfectly. My advisor keep asking me why $\mathcal H^{N-1}$ a.e. hold and it confuse me a lot... By the way, do you think there is any problem for mutual intersections assumption?

Comment: Sorry I don;t understand your notation. Is B(x,r) an N-dimensional ball?

Comment: @PieroD'Ancona ah sorry, fixed!